# How to handle touch gesture for press-hold-slide-release between 2 buttons

Tags: android, button, popupwindow

I am trying to create a menu that will behave much like the on-screen keypad of Android, wherein when press-holding a key with accented characters like "i", a popup menu for the accented characters is displayed. Then sliding the finger into the button of any accented character within the popup menu highlights/selects the button, and finally releasing the finger, inputs the accented character into the target textbox. I have seen this behavior in Android v2.3, but not on the older versions. Not sure if this is a new feature?

I would like to know how to handle the touch gesture such that main button (e.g. "i") will react to press and hold touch events, and then after the popup appears, the button for "ï" will react to the point and release touch events? The user will not need to release the finger, thus the motion will be a press-hold-slide-release between 2 buttons.

I have tried to find the code used in the Android keypad but was not successful as I only got directed to CharacterPickerDialog which does not show the press-hold-slide-release between 2 buttons, since it requires the user to release the finger before selecting a button in the popup menu.

Hope anyone can provide some info and insights on this. Thanks in advance!